# Hypergraph edge colouring

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, discrete-mathematics

I'm interested in knowing if finding the edge-chromatic number of a $k$-uniform $k$-partite hypergraph is NP-hard for $k\geq 3$ Could anyone provide a reference for the result? By edge-chromatic number i mean the smallest number of colours assigned to the edges such that incident edges receive different colours.

Comment: What about tripartite graphs, do you know the answer for those?

Comment: No, i'm assuming it's hard but i'd love to see the reduction if you have a reference?

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36114/what-is-known-about-the-hardness-of-the-chromatic-index-for-restricted-graph-cla

Comment: Sorry where in that post does it reference a paper proving hardness for 3-partite 3-uniform hypergraphs?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Did you want a link to this paper? doi:10.1016/0166-218X(91)90010-T

Comment: I was asking if there is a link to a paper which provides a proof that edge colouring for 3-uniform 3-partite hypergraphs is NP-hard

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know anything more about the problem. In fact, I know even less than three months ago, as I'm just forgetting.